# Why do my colours completely fade when I merge layers or export to jpeg?

Tags: photoshop, color, layers

I’ve been working on a colourful image but when I export it to jpeg, the colours are almost gone. Sure, I understand saving in jpeg can lead to change in colour but.. this is the most massive loss of saturation I’ve seen. The same thing happens if I merge down as well.

This is what my layers look like

[image]

Am I missing something obvious?

The difference:

[image: left is the file still in PS and right is my jpeg]

The purple colour especially seems to not appear. I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Am i working in the wrong colour space?

How can I get the colours to pop in my export files?

Comment: If it fades just by flattening the image (still in Photoshop), then it has nothing to do with jpeg and with saving as such. But I'd struggle to explain such behaviour.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as it would probably be a better fit for https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com It actually has nothing to do with photography.

Comment: This can/does affect editing of photographs as well IME. So I gave an answer instead of voting to close.

Comment: What JPEG settings are you using? What color space are you using? What viewer are you using?

Answer (score 2):

It is due to the way PS flattens an image; by default it (sometimes?) preserves the layer masks; and the underlying layer's mask will mask the layer above. If you attempt to merge/flatten only two layers PS will pop up a warning about this; and it gives you an option of applying the mask of the underlying layer before merging. You do not get the option when you export, flatten a group of layers, or flatten the entire layer stack.

The behavior also seems to be dependent on what is being flattened/merged e.g. adjustment/vector layers vs image layers (or if an image layer is included). I can't really say for certain exactly when it will/won't happen.
In your case, it appears that the layer "1"s mask is masking some/all of the edits above it...

The way I have found to get around it is to create a new top layer and then merge visible into it (shift-opt-cmd-E). This copies the current view as a new image on top of all other layers; then turn off all other layers below before exporting/flattening (alt/option click on the top layer's view (eye) button). Your result should then be what you were expecting.

Comment: OP says this happens when "I export it to jpeg" and notes "The same thing happens if I merge down as well"  – so the problem occurs when Photoshop is doing the flattening during export, all layers together at once.  What you describe seems like a Photoshop bug, but OP's problem may be color space or export settings. Can't tell, since OP does not provide them.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long-standing problem with fine details and rendering to a display when layers are using different blending modes.  Unfortunately, there is no fix for it, as it's image-dependent.